# How to Make the Split Gem Ignore Developers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a real problem with A/B testing lately: my developers and employees are seriously skewing the numbers. For google analytics and other platforms you can get people to install a plugin which removes this problem, but what about in rails? (specifically using the Split gem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filtering part of Split gem to filter for your developers. https://github.com/andrew/split#filtering

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can use a query parameter to force a specific version of the site that will not be counted towards the results:

> > Overriding alternatives
>
> For development and testing, you may wish to force your app to always
>   return an alternative. You can do this by passing it as a parameter in
>   the url.
>
> If you have an experiment called button_color with alternatives called
>   red and blue used on your homepage, a url such as:
>
> http://myawesomesite.com?button_color=red will always have red
>   buttons. This won't be stored in your session or count towards to
>   results, unless you set the store_override configuration option.

https://github.com/andrew/split